# Добавление ключа и значения в "словарный" словарь

Tags: c#

Подскажите как добавить ключ и значение в словарь такого типо

```
public static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> Dic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

Такой способ работать не будит

```
Dic.Add("1234", "1234", 1234);
```

Comment: Имейте в виду, скорее всего вам не нужен словарь словарей - создайте нормальную понятную структуру классов, мыслите в ООП

Answer (score 2):

Если вложенный словарь уже существует:

```
Dic[key1][key2] = value;
Dic[key1].Add(key2, value);
```

Если нет:

```
Dic.Add(key1, new Dictionary<string, int> { { key2, value } });
```

Если вы не знаете существует ли он:

```
Dictionary<string, int> inner;
if (!Dic.TryGetValue(key1, out inner))
     Dic.Add(key1, inner = new Dictionary<string, int>());
inner[key2] = value;
```

---

Но, скорее всего, тут можно обойтись одним словарем с составным ключом:

```
static Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int> Dic = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int>();
```

Добавление в такой словарь будет довольно простым:

```
Dic.Add(Tuple.Create(key1, key2), value);
```

Получение значения будет выглядеть аналогично.

Если вы используйте последнюю версию C# - то также можно воспользоваться новым языковым средством:

```
static Dictionary<(string, string), int> Dic = new Dictionary<(string, string), int>();

Dic.Add((key1, key2), value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dic["1234"].Add("1234", 1234);
```

или

```
Dic["1234"]["1234"] = 1234;
```

При условии, что элемент с ключом "1234" уже существует, иначе, нужно его предварительно добавить:

```
Dic.Add("1234", new Dictionary<string, int>());
```

или

```
Dic["1234"] = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Либо сразу создаем внутренний словарь с добавленным элементом:

```
Dic["1234"] = new Dictionary<string, int> { ["1234"] = 1234 };
```